# How to factor RSA modulus given the public and private exponent?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have a RSA private key with modulus `m`, public exponent `e` and private exponent `d`, but the program I am using needs the modulus's prime factors `p` and `q`.

Is it possible to use `e` and `d` to get `p` and `q`?

Comment: is there any code in openssl to perform this task

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes -- once you know the modulus N, and public/private exponents d and e, it is not too difficult to obtain p and q such that N=pq.

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/199902/boneh.pdf) by Dan Boneh describes an algorithm for doing so.  It relies
on the fact that, by definition,

de = 1 mod phi(N).

For any randomly chosen "witness" 
in (2,N), there is about a 50% chance of being able to use it to find a nontrivial 
square root of 1 mod N (call it x).  Then gcd(x-1,N) gives one of the factors.

Comment: Just nitpicking: all RSA needs is that _de = 1_ mod _p-1_ and mod _q-1_, so that's _de = 1_ mod _lcm(p-1,q-1)_ which is a strict divisor of _phi(N)_ (using _phi(N)_ is just the way RSA was first described). However, the method described by Boneh works in the general case as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the open source tool I have developed in 2009 that converts RSA keys between the SFM format (n,e,d) and CRT format (p,q,dp,dq,u), and the other way around. It is on SourceForge : http://rsaconverter.sourceforge.net/

The algorithm I implemented is based on ideas presented by Dan Boneh, as described by the previous answer.

I hope this will be useful.

Mounir IDRASSI - IDRIX

Comment: actually i need a code in openssl to perform this task , can u provide if available

Comment: You can look at the file librsaconverter.c from my project RsaConverter on SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/p/rsaconverter/code/HEAD/tree/Trunk/src/librsaconverter.c. There you will find the implementation of the function SfmToCrt that calculate RSA primes from public modulus and private exponent.

Answer (score 6):

I posted a response on the crypto stack exchange answering the same question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/is-sharing-the-modulus-for-multiple-rsa-key-pairs-secure/14713).  It uses the same approach as outlined in Boneh's paper, but does a lot more explanation as to how it actually works.  I also try to assume a minimal amount of prior knowledge.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I put in the effort to dig through [Boneh's paper](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf). The "algorithm" for deriving `(p, q)` from `(n, d)` is buried at the end of §1.1, coded in maths jargon, and left as an exercise for the reader to render out of his (rather terse) *proof* that it's *efficient* to do so.

> Let 〈*N*, *e*〉 be an RSA public key. Given the private key *d*, one can efficiently factor the modulus *N* = *pq*.
>
> **Proof.** Compute *k* = *de* − 1. By definition of *d* and *e* we know that *k* is a multiple of *φ*(*N*). Since *φ*(*N*) is even, *k* = 2<sup>*t*</sup>*r* with *r* odd and *t* ≥ 1. We have *g*<sup>*k*</sup> = 1 for every *g* ∈ ℤ<sub>*N*</sub><sup>×</sup>, and therefore *g*<sup>*k*/2</sup> is a square root of unity modulo *N*. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, 1 has four square roots modulo *N* = *pq*. Two of these square roots are ±1. The other two are ±*x* where *x* satisfies *x* = 1 mod *p* and *x* = −1 mod *q*. Using either one of these last two square roots, the factorization of *N* is revealed by computing gcd(*x* − 1, *N*). A straightforward argument shows that if *g* is chosen at random from ℤ<sub>*N*</sub><sup>×</sup> then with probability at least 1/2 (over the choice of *g*) one of the elements in the sequence *g*<sup>*k*/2</sup>, *g*<sup>*k*/4</sup>, …, *g*<sup>*k*/2<sup>*t*</sup></sup> mod *N* is a square root of unity that reveals the factorization of *N*. All elements in the sequence can be efficiently computed in time *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>) where *n* = log<sub>2</sub>(*N*).

Obviously, this is pretty close to meaningless for anyone who doesn't know what [`$Z_N^\ast$`](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496759/188128#comments-4496759) is, and has a pretty nonlinear structure that takes a good deal of time to twist into a linear algorithm.

So here is the worked solution:

```py
from random import randrange
from math import gcd


def ned_to_pqe(secret_key):
    """
    https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#:~:text=Given%20d%2C,reveals%20the%20factorization%20of%20N%2E
    """
    n, e, d = secret_key
    k = d * e - 1
    t = bit_scan1(k)
    trivial_sqrt1 = {1, n - 1}
    while True:
        g = randrange(2, n - 1)
        for j in range(1, t + 1):
            x = pow(g, k >> j, n)
            if pow(x, 2, n) == 1:
                if x in trivial_sqrt1: continue
                p = gcd(x - 1, n)
                q = n // p
                if q > p: p, q = q, p
                return p, q, e


def pqe_to_ned(secret_key):
    p, q, e = secret_key
    n = p * q
    l = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    d = pow(e, -1, l)
    return n, e, d


def bit_scan1(i):
    """
    https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpz.html#mpz.bit_scan1
    """
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552117/1874170
    return (i & -i).bit_length() - 1


def test():
    secret_key = (
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100
        # Should take upwards of an hour to factor on a consumer desktop ca. 2022
        1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139,
        65537,
        1435319569480661473883310243084583371347212233430112391255270984679722445287591616684593449660400673
    )
    if secret_key != pqe_to_ned(ned_to_pqe(secret_key)):
        raise ValueError


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    print("Self-test OK")
```

Live demo (JS):

```js
function ned_to_pqe({n, e, d}) {
  // https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#:~:text=Given%20d%2C,reveals%20the%20factorization%20of%20N%2E
  let k = d * e - 1n;
  let t = scan1(k);
  let trivial_sqrt1 = new Set([1n, n - 1n]);
  while (true) {
    let g = insecure_randrange(2n, n - 1n);
    for ( let j = t ; j > 0 ; --j ) {
      let x = bn_powMod(g, k >> j, n);
      if (bn_powMod(x, 2n, n) === 1n) {
        if (trivial_sqrt1.has(x)) continue;
        let p = gcd(x - 1n, n), q = n/p;
        if (q > p) [p, q] = [q, p];
        return {p, q, e};
      }
    }
  }
}


function pqe_to_ned({p, q, e}) {
  let n = p * q;
  let l = (p - 1n) * (q - 1n);
  let d = bn_modInv(e, l);
  return {n, e, d};
}


function bn_powMod(x, e, m) {
  // h/t https://umaranis.com/2018/07/12/calculate-modular-exponentiation-powermod-in-javascript-ap-n/
  if (m === 1n) return 0n;
  let y = 1n;
  x = x % m;
  while (e > 0n) {
    if (e % 2n === 1n)  //odd number
      y = (y * x) % m;
    e = e >> 1n;  //divide by 2
    x = (x * x) % m;
  }
  return y;
}


function bn_modInv(x, m) {
  // TOY IMPLEMENTATION
  // DO NOT USE IN GENERAL-PURPOSE CODE
  // h/t https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#C
  let m0 = m, t, q;
  let x0 = 0n, y = 1n;
  if (m === 1n) return 1n;
  while (x > 1n) {
    q = x / m;
    t = m;
    m = x % m;
    x = t;
    t = x0;
    x0 = y - q * x0;
    y = t;
  }
  if (y < 0n) y += m0;
  return y;
}


function gcd(a, b) {
  // h/t https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445304/1874170
  while (b) {
    [a, b] = [b, a % b];
  }
  return a;
}


function scan1(i) {
  // https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling#mpz_scan1
  let k = 0n;
  if ( i !== 0n ) {
    while( (i & 1n) === 0n ) {
      i >>= 1n;
      k += 1n;
    }
  }
  return k;
}


function insecure_randrange(a, b) {
  // h/t https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1916
  let numerator = 0n;
  let denominator = 1n;
  let n = (b - a);
  while (true) {
    numerator <<= 1n;
    denominator <<= 1n;
    numerator |= BigInt(Math.random()>1/2);
    if (denominator >= n) {
      if (numerator < n)
        return a + numerator;
      numerator -= n;
      denominator -= n;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:" onsubmit="(({target:form,submitter:{value:action}})=>{eval(action)(form)})(event)">
<p>
<label for="p">p=</label><input name="p" value="37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199" /><br />
<label for="q">q=</label><input name="q" value="40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061" /><br />
<label for="n">n=</label><input name="n" /><br />
<label for="e">e=</label><input name="e" placeholder="65537" /><br />
<label for="d">d=</label><input name="d" /><br />
</p>
<p>
<button type="submit" value="pqe2nd">Get (n,d) from (p,q,e)</button><br />
<button type="submit" value="delpq">Forget (p,q)</button><br />
<button type="submit" value="ned2pq">Get (p,q) from (n,e,d)</button>
</form>

<script>
function pqe2nd({elements}) {
  if (!elements['e'].value) elements['e'].value = elements['e'].placeholder;
  let p = BigInt(elements['p'].value||undefined);
  let q = BigInt(elements['q'].value||undefined);
  let e = BigInt(elements['e'].value||undefined);
  let {n, d} = pqe_to_ned({p,q,e});
  elements['n'].value = n.toString();
  elements['d'].value = d.toString();
}
function ned2pq({elements}) {
  if (!elements['e'].value) elements['e'].value = elements['e'].placeholder;
  let n = BigInt(elements['n'].value||undefined);
  let e = BigInt(elements['e'].value||undefined);
  let d = BigInt(elements['d'].value||undefined);
  let {p, q} = ned_to_pqe({n,e,d});
  elements['p'].value = p.toString();
  elements['q'].value = q.toString();
}
function delpq({elements}) {
  elements['p'].value = null;
  elements['q'].value = null;
}
</script>
```

---

To answer the question as-stated in the title: factoring `N` entails *finding* `N`. But [you cannot, in the general case, derive `N` from `(e, d)`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81620/8287). Therefore, you cannot, in the general case, derive the factors of `N` from `(e, d)`; QED.

> finding *n* from (*e*, *d*) is computationally feasible with fair probability, or even certainty, for a **small** but observable fraction of RSA keys of practical interest

If you want to try to do so anyway, you'll need to be able to factorize `e * d - 1` (if I understand the above-linked answer correctly):

```py
from itertools import permutations


def ed_to_pq(e, d):
    # NOT ALWAYS POSSIBLE -- the number e*d-1 must be small enough to factorize
    # h/t https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81620/8287
    factors = factorize(e * d - 1)
    factors.sort()
    # Unimplemented optimization:
    #   if two factors are larger than (p * q).bit_length()//4
    #   and the greater of (p, q) is not many times bigger than the lesser,
    #   then you can safely assume that the large factors belong to (p-1) and (q-1)
    #   and thereby reduce the number of iterations in the following loops
    # Unimplemented optimization:
    #   permutations are overkill for this partitioning scheme;
    #   a clever mathematician could come up with something more efficient
    # Unimplemented optimization:
    #   prune permutations based on "sanity" factor of logarithm knapsacking
    l = len(factors)
    for arrangement in permutations(factors):
        for l_pm1 in range(1, l - 1):
            for l_qm1 in range(1, l_pm1):
                pm1 = prod(arrangement[:l_pm1])
                qm1 = prod(arrangement[l_pm1:l_pm1+l_qm1])
                try:
                    if pow(e, -1, pm1 * qm1) == d:
                        return (pm1 + 1, qm1 + 1)
                except Exception:
                    pass


from functools import reduce
from operator import mul


def prod(l):
    return reduce(mul, l)
```

Comment: *[When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/202692)*

Comment: w/r/t `l_pm1, l_qm1` -- I'm not sure if there is a cleaner way to [iterate through those](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4499917/188128).