# How to separate a rectangle into an equal number of squares?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, geometry

Let's say I have a `<div>` rectangle sized 1400x700 pixels. Let's call it a "canvas."

I want to fill it with a number of enlarged "pixels" if you will - squares of random color and opacity. Randomly. Some will fade in, some will fade out. That's easy enough.

The HTML structure should look like:

```
div#canvas
  div.pixel
  div.pixel
  div.pixel
  div.pixel
```

How do I take the original dimensions of the rectangle and arrive at a number of square divs that are guaranteed to fill the whole "canvas" to the brim?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The size of the squares should be variable somehow. The idea is to "pixelate" the background image but in an undulating fashion, though that's a mental issue and not a programming one.

Comment: How big are the squares?

Comment: @Paulie_D Good question. Proportional to the size of the canvas. Let's say like 5%ish? I'll update the question

Comment: Assuming the square needs to have integral side length in pixels, the largest square whose side length divides both the width and height of the rectangle will have side length equal to the [greatest common divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445231/js-how-to-find-the-greatest-common-divisor) of the rectangle width and height.

Comment: @dbc This is the answer I wanted. Care to elaborate a little and I'll set it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a seperate dom element for each "pixel"? I'd consider to just use a single element with a custom background gradient like this:

http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#checkerboard

Comment: Yes they do because they'll appear and disappear at random / change opacity / etc. I dont think the CSS3 checkerboard can do that?