# check if values in array have common difference

Tags: javascript

I have a sample array as

const arr=[0,2,4,6]

I want to check if they have a common difference in them, which is `2` and yes in above array.

There could be more efficient way to do this. I tried using a simple `for` loop as:

```js
const arr = [0,2,4,6];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
  if(arr[i]+2==arr[i+1]){
    console.log(true);
   }
   else{
     console.log(false);   
   }
}
```

This could give me result as `true`,`true`,`true` and push all values to a new array then check if all are true and finally I would get `true`

It would be helpful if there is a more efficient way to do this; any help appreciated.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS how to find the greatest common divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445231/js-how-to-find-the-greatest-common-divisor)

Comment: @Justinas I don't think OP wants to check if the array has a common divisor. They want to check if the difference between the consecutive items is same through the array.

Comment: as per eg concerned i would say the difference is `2` i want to check , in more mathematical way ,an arithmetic sequence with difference as `2` hope its clear , `a+(n-1)*d` , `d=2`

Comment: if any of them don't match just return false immediately

Comment: @user120242 yes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the array is sorted, you can do it pretty simply with `.every()`.

```js
const arr = [0,2,4,6];
const itvl = arr[1] - arr[0];
const result = arr.slice(0, -1).every((n, i) =>
  itvl === arr[i + 1] - n
)
console.log(result);
```

This starts off by calculating the first interval, then it iterates the array (except the last index) using `.every()` to test that the next index minus the current one is equal to that pre-calculated index.

Comment: In terms of performance, you don't stop as soon as you found a "false", so that's not optimized.

Comment: @djcaesar9114: It does stop. That's one of the benefits of using `.every()`;  it stops as soon as it is proven that not every iteration returns `true`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every  , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some  , probably the cleanest way to express this (

Comment: @dj No problem. The `.some()` method is optimized that way too.

Comment: so `every` would check for all ? as per links

Comment: every call to the function in every must return true for every to return true, otherwise false.

Comment: +1 for being the only solution using higher a order function instead of explicit looping. And even if it wasn't optimal, it honestly wouldn't invalidate the answer.

Comment: @gyohza OP explicitly asked for optimal solution, so likely it's part of the assignment and would invalidate the answer

Comment: Optimization is a question of individual implementations. That's pretty tough to track consistently.

Comment: For a simple problem like this?  If I gave a student an assignment like this and said, find the most efficient way to do this problem, would you really be expecting anything else?  Obviously the only thing expected from this is knowing you can terminate the loop early.

Comment: I get that @user120242 , thanks again for more exp indeed

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "efficient" != "optimal". But yeah, I guess it always makes sense to go for an optimal solution (if they exist) when you want to improve efficiency.

Comment: i have one more q, may i know how to check all this after first values sum to 4 , e.g. `arr=[1,3,4,6,8]` , here check only `4,6,8` excluding `1,3`

Comment: change slice(0, to slice(indextostartat  [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: `indextostartat` can be known as ? sorry confused , because it may [0,4,....],[1,3...],[1,0,2,1...]

Comment: read what slice does at the link.  it'll be good to know anyways

Comment: slice i understood , but in my comment may i know how could i get `indextostart` value for diff scenarios mentioned

Comment: add a condition for sum<=4, or do another check first, and use the index in the slice

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. It's better to stop as soon as you find a false rather than testing all the values.

```js
const arr=[0,2,4,6]

var r = true
for (var i=1; i<arr.length-1 && r; i++) {
  r = ((arr[i+1] - arr[i]) == (arr[i] - arr[i-1]))
}

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Checks if numbers sum up to desired sum and if rest of numbers have same difference as desired in comments.  (This should be a separate question.)

add up until s >= sum.  return false if s isn't equal to set sum
if numbers left <= 2 return true
get difference of first 2 numbers
check difference of numbers, if not same difference return false
differences all same, return true

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];
const sum = 4

check = arr => {
let s = 0,
    idx = arr.findIndex(x => (s+=x) >= sum ) + 1

if(s !== sum) return false
if(arr.length - idx < 3) return true

const diff = arr[idx+1] - arr[idx]

while(++idx<arr.length-1)
 if(arr[idx+1] - arr[idx] !== diff) return false
return true
}


arr = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
console.log(
check(arr)
)

arr = [0, 1, 3]
console.log(
check(arr)
)

arr = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 11]
console.log(
check(arr)
)
```

Comment: Actually you don't handle if the difference is different from 2.

Comment: he didn't ask for that.  he's probably learning for an assignment or something.  he just needs to know how to terminate his loop early.

Comment: He didn't say the difference was always 2, he wrote "which is 2 and yes in above array" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you mean by difference is the step value. For that, first find the difference between the first two elements ; then check whether the same difference holds for all consecutive values.

```
const arr = [0, 2, 4, 6];
let flag = true;
diff = arr[1] - arr[0];
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length-1; i++){
           if(arr[i+1] - arr[i]  != diff ){
              flag = false;
              break;
           } 


     }
console.log(flag)
```

The code assumes the array size is atleast 2. Add an if guard if this is not always guaranteed.

Comment: nice (and upvoted!) solution, though you don't need the `else` part, and you're logging twice in case of falsehood